# Regex in WWW::Mechanize in Perl

Tags: regex, www-mechanize

I am not sure what is the correct syntax for the url_regex used in WWW::Mechanize.

I am collecting all the links from a web page that start with an http:// and they are of the following format:

```
http://google.com
```

and not,

```
http://google.com/dir/
http://google.com/dir/dir2/
```

So, I use the following:

```
@links=$mech->find_all_links(url_regex=>qr/^http:\/\/.*?\//)
```

And this still captures the URLs with sub paths in them.

I have tested my regex on regexpal.com and it works good. But for some reason, url_regex expects a different syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You should use:*

```
@links=$mech->find_all_links(url_regex=>qr/^http:\/\/[^\/]*\/?$/)
```

*which reads:*

String has to start `^` with `http://` followed by any combination (even none/empty) of characters others than slash `[^\/]*` followed by optional slash `\/?` at the end `$`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you please explain your regex a bit more? My regex was not working since dot would match a forward slash character also, so we need to negate it in the character class. Is that the reason?